# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new JdRes())

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am writing jasmine test spec for an angular controller.
Here, I get the error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new JdRes())` - though I've defined it as

```
JdRes = jasmine.createSpy('JdRes');
```

The code segment in the controller is as follows

```
function (myService, $scope, $attrs, $q, $parse) {
    'use strict';

    var JdRes, resource;

    JdRes = myService('JdRes');
    resource = new JdRes();
}
```

Comment: Why is there no closing `}` in your function?

Answer (score 9):

Based on the information you've provided, the only conclusion I can make is that `jasmine.createSpy('JdRes')` returns `undefined`.

That means that either `jasmine.createSpy` doesn't have a `return` statement, or it tries to return something that has a value of `undefined`. You should check if the function does indeed have a `return` statement, and if it does, its returned value is not `undefined`. There's nothing further I can tell you.

Comment: For posterity, this behavior also occurs if you do `spyOn(obj, 'someMethod').and.return('some value')`.  It should be `.and.returnValue('some value')`

Answer (score 2):

This will occur also when you inject a different number of items than the number of arguments to the function - either way, I believe. For example:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('controllers').controller('myController', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$scope',
    '$state',
    '$compile',
    'aService',
    'aServiceNotDefinedInConstructorArgs'];

function MyController('$scope',
    '$state',
    '$compile',
    'aService') {

    var vm = this;
    ...
}
```

Here the difference is aServiceNotDefinedInConstructorArgs is being injected but is not argument to MyController.